# How to change the z-index with a javascript inside of C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, z-index, scriptmanager

I want to use javascript inside of a c# if else-statement.
I'm using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to do that.
But I don't know, what to write between the script tags.
I've already tried it with alert(\"ok\") and it worked.

```
else if (n == 2 && chart.Width == "50%")
                    {
                        literal = ltrRenderChart2;
                        string str = "<script>$(ltrRenderChart2).css(\"z-index\",0) </script>";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(ltrRenderChart2, ltrRenderChart2.GetType(), "Script", str, false);
```

These are my div's and I want to change the z-index.

```
      <div id="chart1"style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:0; ">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1;">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1;">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart4" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`asp:Literal` just renders out the HTML and so you cannot find them when you *View Source* of the page. What you need to do is to give the parent div an id and then call it by that ID

Update: Change it to an `asp:Panel` so that a div gets rendered.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1">
    <asp:Panel ID="ltrRenderChart2" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Code-behind

```
var literalID = ltrRenderChart2.ClientID;
string str = "<script>$('#" + literalID + "').parent().css(\"z-index\",0) </script>";
```

Comment: So you mean like I did in the first div? If i would do it in the second div, it should look like this.     else if (n == 2 && chart.Width == "50%")
                        {
                            literal = ltrRenderChart2;
                            string script = "<script>$(\"#chart2\").css(\"z-index\",\"0\");</script>";
                            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(ltrRenderChart2, ltrRenderChart2.GetType(), "Script", script, false);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like that in the past, but be aware that I just wrote this off the top of my head. Hopefully you get the gist, you could add a class with the z-idex:0 and add that class to the item you want...

```
  ltrRenderChart2.Style.Add("z-index", 0);
```

-g

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you are not using '#' while referencing

```
string str = "<script>$(ltrRenderChart2).css(\"z-index\",0) </script>";
```

instead of this, write down:

```
string str = "<script>$(\"#ltrRenderChart2\").css(\"z-index\",\"0\");</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string script = " <script type='text/javascript'>function change() { document.getElementById('chart1').style.zIndex = '-1';}</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", script, true);
```

Comment: may be you can add the change function in javascript and call it from code behind like this Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "change()", true);